# VueJS variables in a docker file

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a config file with API URL under the path "src/config.js":

```
const API_URL = 'https://some-url-here.com'

export default {
  API_URL: API_URL
}
```

And a Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

How can i make that `API_URL` available to docker, so devops could change that url?

Comment: You can define environment variables inside Dockerfile;

`ENV API_URL = some_url`

Then in your `src/config.js` file you can access it via `process.env.API_URL`

Comment: if i set `process.env.API_URL` and in "config/dev.env.js" i'll add `module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  API_URL: '"https://url.com"'
})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Vue-cli 2.9, you can set ENV variables in a "config" directory.

For example: "config/dev.env.js":

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  API_URL: '"https://server.com"'
})
```

Then you can use it in your client :

```
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL
export default {
  API_URL: API_URL,
}
```